# Where is my mistake?

Tags: calculus

I have the following question in an online quiz:

> A piecewise function $f$ is defined by:
>
> $f(x) = px-p$ when $x$ is less than 1, and
>
> $f(x)=0$ otherwise.
>
> What value of $p$ makes $f$ continuous at $x=1$?

I answered $p=1$, which was one of the multiple choice answers, but it says that I am wrong. What is my mistake? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Was there an option "Any value"?

Comment: Yes, Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange question as 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow1}px-p = p-p=0 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}}f(x).
$$
So it is continuous for any value of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The left side limit and the right side limit of the function as $x\to 1$, for any value of $p$, is zero. Therefore the function is always continuous at $x=1$ (for any $p$).